# Deforming a complex object by shrinking or expanding the bottom only?

Tags: scale, 3d-printing

I want to be able to deform a complex object by shrinking the base but leaving the top as it is.

For example, if I had a square I'd end up with a trapezoid, while a cylined would be an inverted cone, but done on a much more complicated object like a building (So top story is disproportionately large and the bottom is disproportionately small. As if you were standing at the bottom and looking up at it with a wide angle lense?

I intend to 3D print the model.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a *Lattice* modifier (you need to create a lattice cage, scale it in *Object* so that it contains your object, then deform it in *Edit* mode):

[image]

You can also use the *Simple Deform* modifier (*Taper* mode):

[image]

Comment: Taper Modifier, I'm an idiot for not thinking of that.

Comment: Also you can create an empty to decide how you want it to act on the deformation